# Proper XML serialization for web service PUT/POST method

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf

I have WCF web service, which have next PUT method

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
void ScanPatient(PatientInfo patientInfo);

//...

[XmlRoot("PatientInfo")]
public class PatientInfo
{
    [XmlElement("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("SSN")]
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Birthday")]
    public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("RequestedClientID")]
    public Guid RequestedClientID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("patientId")]
    public Guid patientId { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using WebRequest to communicate with this service

```
private void ExecuteWebServiceCommand(string method, string command, string parameters = "")
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(command));
    request.ContentType = "application/xml";
    request.Method = method;

    string responseFromServer = null;
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameters);

    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    using (var newStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
    var response = request.GetResponse();
}
```

It works perfectly, if for `parameters` next formatting is used:

```
<PatientInfo><FirstName>{0}</FirstName><LastName>{1}</LastName><RequestedClientID>{2}</RequestedClientID></PatientInfo>
```

Obviously, I don't want to have manual data composing, since every new field will require update of template. So, i'm trying to use `XMLSerializer`.

```
private string SerializeToString(object data)
{
    if (data == null) return null;
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");

    using (var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter())
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType(), "");
        serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, data, ns);
        return stringwriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

But I'm getting next result when serializing `PatientInfo`:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n<PatientInfo>\r\n  <FirstName>Andrew</FirstName>\r\n  <LastName>Fox</LastName>\r\n  <Birthday d2p1:nil=\"true\" xmlns:d2p1=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" />\r\n  <RequestedClientID>2c547deb-2395-4334-b1b0-58e6562b5843</RequestedClientID>\r\n  <patientId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</patientId>\r\n</PatientInfo>"
```

And it does not fit for `ExecuteWebServiceCommand`, giving me (400) Bad Request exception.

So, how can I properly serialize object to XML, to make it suitable for such code? Or how can I modity code to accept such data?

Comment: At least, I'd like to know, how can i configure serializer to remove that "prolog" thing and control characters from result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an [`XmlWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.create(v=vs.110).aspx) which you instantiate with the correct [`XmlWriterSettings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings(v=vs.110).aspx) to omit the Xml declaration and have no newlines on serialization. When applying this to your code you'll end up with this:

```
private string SerializeToString(object data)
{
    if (data == null) return null;
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");

    // what should the XmlWriter do?
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
        NewLineChars = ""
    };

    using (var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter())
    {
       // Use an XmlWriter to wrap the StringWriter
       using(var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringwriter, settings))
       {
           var serializer = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType(), "");
           // serialize to the XmlWriter instance
           serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, data, ns);
           return stringwriter.ToString();
       }
    }
}
```

Which will give me this result:

> <PatientInfo><FirstName>Foo</FirstName><Birthday>2015-12-19T16:21:48.4009949+01:00</Birthday><RequestedClientID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</RequestedClientID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</patientId></PatientInfo>